# Show webpage with no URL bar, navigation bar, etc

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, web-applications, browser

I'm working on a vb.net web application and want to make it to where when someone puts in a url into the browser or when someone clicks on a shortcut, a new browser window is opened but there is no back or forward, no refresh, no navigation bar, etc.  Does anyone know how to do this or if it's even possible?  I just want the browser shell essentially.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would advice against this - the browser is the users domain, don't mess with it.  Are there any particular reasons for your choice of functionality?

Any ways to make this possible will be based on Javascript, and this can always be disabled by the user.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in javascript code behind cannot open new browser windows.  Take a look [here](http://www.pageresource.com/jscript/jwinopen.htm).

Answer (score 0):

you can do this with javascript using the [window.open()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp) method.